# Unable to properly parse json file

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on a random quote app, and I need to parse ajson file through an http connection. I'm succesfully stablishing the connection; and fetching json data, but when I try parsing it, it seems I'm getting the keys, value, or object not mapped correctly. Or maybe I'm not using the correct code. Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
package com.example.george.radonquote;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar myToolbar;
    String randQuote;
    String author;
    TextView quoteTextView;
    ImageView bgImageView;
    ImageView nextImageView;
    String url = "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting the ActionBar for the activity
        myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        quoteTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote_text);
        nextImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next_quote);

        /*onclick listener for next quote*/
        nextImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FetchQuote fetchQuote = new FetchQuote();
                fetchQuote.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    * async class to get random quote in background
    */
    class FetchQuote extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String quote = "";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fetching Quote!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        /*
        * making connection and parsing json data
        */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL uri = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = "";
                while(line != null) {
                    Log.v("line: ",line);
                    line = bf.readLine();
                    quote += line;
                }
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(quote);
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(0);
                randQuote = jo.get("content").toString().replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","");
                author = jo.get("title").toString();
                Log.v("QUOTE", randQuote+" "+author);
            }
            catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
//            Log.v("Post Exec", randQuote);
            quoteTextView.setText(randQuote);

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output of Service- Parsed]

[image: Output of Service- Raw]

Comment: how are we supposed what mapping is wrong , you haven't even posted the response and what mapping are you expecting?

Comment: The response which you are getting is not a valid json. It is starting with `/**/mycallback(`.

Comment: If I can get the callback into a string, then I can parse it!!!

Comment: Try using google protocol buffers, they are simpler and optimized

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a valid json from the url. First rectify your string then parse the json . try below code. This is only a temporary solution.

```
try {
                String requiredString = quote.substring(quote.indexOf("(") + 1, quote.indexOf(")"));
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(requiredString );
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(0);
                randQuote = jo.get("content").toString().replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","");
                author = jo.get("title").toString();
                Log.v("QUOTE", randQuote+" "+author);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `_jsonp=mycallback` parameter in the url.  Using this parameter is causing malformed JSON to be returned to you.

As you can see in [the documentation](https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/), the JSONP parameter is used in JavaScript in order to execute a callback.

Since you're using Java in an Android app, there is no need to specify a callback.

All you need to do is modify the url so that it doesn't define a callback:

```
String url = "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1";
```

Then, the response will be valid formatted JSON, for example:

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":1572,
      "title":"Si Scott",
      "content":"<p>I really like looking at design and thinking: that attention to detail must have taken absolutely ages.<\/p>\n",
      "link":"https:\/\/quotesondesign.com\/si-scott\/",
      "custom_meta":{  
         "Source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.formatmag.com\/art\/si-scott\/\">article<\/a>"
      }
   }
]
```

Then, your existing code should work.  I just tested it, and it logged the correct response:

```
10-06 12:35:52.522 4606-4624/com.example.ex V/QUOTE: Graphic designers find themselves in a role of visual dishwashers for the Information Architects&#8217; chefs.  
                                                                Gunnar Swanson
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/) library and follow the given code

```
String content;
content = Jsoup.parse(content).text();
```

Comment: I tried that, but android studio doesn't recognize the class

Comment: You have to add the jar file or can use gradle import. Download availabel on given website. https://jsoup.org/download OR compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.1'

Comment: This not an incorrect solution but is an alternative solution. Happy programming.